# 502 Bad Gateway Error for Nginx & Passenger in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

Hi my server suddenly failed. I tried to restart nginx using sudo `service nginx restart` but it failed.

Then looking to `error.log`

```
2014/01/03 10:11:44 [crit] 31821#0: *699 connect() to /tmp/passenger.1.0.18076/generation-1/request failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 00.00.00.00, server: staging.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:/tmp/passenger.1.0.18076/generation-1/request:", host: "test.co"
```

Any workarounds will be appreciated.

Comment: show your configs for passenger, and nginx

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a /tmp cleaner daemon on your system that deletes essential Passenger socket files, resulting in the failure you see. Try setting passenger_temp_dir to some directory that is not /tmp: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerTempDir

Comment: In passenger 5: "The passenger_temp_dir option has been replaced by two config options: passenger_instance_registry_dir and passenger_data_buffer_dir."